# how to check if user id exists in foreign table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-8

I need to check if user id exists in foreign table. I have two three tables which are staffs, packaging and cutting.   Both the tables packaging and cutting has staff_id column  I need to check if the staff belongs to packaging or the cutting. So how do I achieve this.

Packaging table

```
 Schema::create('packaging', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('staff_id');
            $table->string('business_name');
            $table->string('tax_id');
            $table->string('phone_number');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Cutting table

```
 Schema::create('cutting', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('staff_id');
            $table->string('business_name');
            $table->string('tax_id');
            $table->string('phone_number');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I tried check using belongsTo and hasOne relation  in Staff Model. but it didn't  work.

```
    public function packaging()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Admin\PackagingCompany::class,'staff_id');
    }
```

Comment: You posted same table

Comment: You can check it by `$staff->packaging()->exists();`

Comment: I tried but packaging  relation returns null

Comment: becaue you didn't define any foreign key on your migration. Make an [edit] and update Cutting migration data

Comment: I am not sure how can I define the foreign key. So any Help.?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply foreign key constraints. See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

```
Schema::create('packaging', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->foreign('staff_id')->references('id')->on('staff');
    $table->string('business_name');
    $table->string('tax_id');
    $table->string('phone_number');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This will prevent you from being able to save a `packaging` record without a valid `staff_id`

You can also apply validation anywhere an input stores a staff member against a packaging model. This would go in your [form request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests) injected into your controller.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'staff_is' => 'exists:staff',
    ];
}
```

You also mentioned that you need to check if the staff member is associated with the `packaging` or `cutting` table.
With the kind of relationship you have in the migrations you've given, a staff member could belong to both `packaging` AND `cutting`. Is that what you want?

In which case you can create `packaging` and `cutting` relationships on your `User` model.

```
public function packaging()
{
    $this-> hasMany(Packaging::class)
}
```

And then query users that have any `packaging` records by doing:

```
// Retrieve all users that have at least one packaging record...
$users = User::has('packaging')->get();
```